# Materials to be avoided during Chatur Masa Vrata?

Tags: belief, culture, tradition, food

What are the materials  should be discarded each month in this 4 month vrata  period?  Like dal,cumins,milk, curd etc, Vegetable, fruits.

Comment: I have provided answer only related food materials to be avoided during chaturmas period. As you have not clearly asked about other materials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chaturmas’ is the period of four months from Ashadh Shukla Ekadashi (Eleventh day of the bright fortnight of the Hindu lunar month of Ashadh) to Kartik Shukla Ekadashi (Eleventh day of the bright fortnight of the Hindu lunar month of Kartik) or Ashadh Pournima (Full-moon day) to Kartik Pournima.

This four months period  in a year is assigned  for penance, austerities, fasting, bathing in holy rivers and religious observances for all. Devotees   observe some form of vow, be it of silence or not eating  a favourite food item, or taking only a single meal  a day.

During this period Deities or Gods take  sleep or Mahanidra.So it's believed that 
demons become active during this time.  The scriptures say that, ‘to protect oneself from these demons each one should undertake some vrat (Vowed religious observance).

> **वार्षिकांश्चतुरो मासान् वाहयेत् केनचिन्नरः ।**
>
> **व्रतेन न चेदाप्नोति किल्मिषं वत्सरोद्भवम् ।।**
>
> Meaning : Every year during chaturmas, we should undertake some vrat
>   otherwise we will incur the sin of samvatsarodbhav.

Comming to your question , what materials is to be avoided is i think pretty personal question and may vary from region to region .But according to beliefs.

**According to popular belief...**

Devotee,s avoide certain food iteams. e.g. Salty foods, Spicy foods,  In some regions devotees avoide certain food iteams during each months.

**In Shravan Month they avoid leafy vegetables , Non-Vegetarian food etc.**

**During Bhadrapada  Month curd is avoided.**

**In Ashwin Month Milk is avoided.**

**In Kartik Month Dal, Pulses are avoided.**

Comment: @Pushkar---I heard that In Shravan month pulses are avoided including  frying of jeerak,mustartd etc.  2 and 3 are correct. Fourth month all dals and vegetable with multi seeds are avoided. Vegetable having single seed and no seed like Amla, plantain flower, raw banana, banana stem and leafy vegetables are allowed. By the way in some purana these are mentioned. I do not know the name of the purana.

Comment: @ParthasarathyRaghavan - There is a tale related to Chaturmas Vrata.That might help you in finding puranik reference.

Comment: @Pushkar---Thanks for your comment. If I am not wrong the purana is skanda wherein the details may be obtained.